# "Topological properties" of scalar multiples of sets in $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, compactness, connectedness

Let $X \subset \mathbb{R}$ with the standard topology.

Let $c \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}$, $X_{c} = \{cx | x \in X \}$.

What "topological properties" does $X_{c}$ inherit from $X$?

I was able to show that if $X$ is open, then $X_{c}$ is, and compactness is easy, as is connectedness. But, what about being meager, or with the property of Baire?

Honestly, I can't think of a topological property that won't be inherited.

Comment: Indeed, these two sets are homeomorphic i.e. if one of them has some topological property, then so does the other one.

Comment: Alright, thank you. My doubt was that the Baire property is defined in terms of of a symmetric differences, which involves intersections, but the image of an intersection need not equal the intersection of the images (what I forgot is that since f is injective, it /is/ the intersection of the images.